# how do I quote a numbered list

Tags: sectioning, lists

I want to make a document which replies to a list of points made in an article as follows:

```
"
Topic
point 1
text

point 2
text

Topic
point 3
text"
```

I tried to achieve this by writing:

```
\section*{\color{magenta}topic1}
\begin{quotation}
\section{point1}
text
\end{quotation}

\begin{quote}
\section{point2}
text
\end{quote}
...
```

This does not work, so I wish to learn how I should code to achieve this goal. I am using the `\section` to get the points numbered throughout the document.

Comment: It's not completely clear (at least to me) what you are trying to achieve. Could you please describe your intent in more detail? Do you want an enumerated list? Should "Topic point1",...,"Topic point3" be sections? What do you mean by quoting a numbered list?

Comment: Yes, my post was "deedited" by the posting script.
Imagen that someone writes a 5 point list of reasons for why humans have never been to the moon. You wish to debunk each of these points with the original comments interleaved in a quotation-style environment. You also wish to have the headlines for each point numbered as they are in the original post which you are responding to. \section numbers the points for you, but refuses to cooperate with the \quote-function to clearly separate quoted material from rebuttals. Either \section or \quote or both have to be changed, I just dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what is required. The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package was used to add color to section titles; an `enumerate` environment was used to produce a list; the resume feature provided by the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package was used..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{magenta}}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Topic 1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Topic 2}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And when I repeat the \section for topic 2, can I get enumerate to continue counting where the previous enumerate left off?

Comment: @ThomasSchwartz I've edited my answer providing this option (using `resume`, from the `enumitem` package); see my updated answer. Do you also need some automatic numbering for the topics (the titles in magenta color)?

Comment: Not for this text, but it would be good to know how for future reference anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasSchwartz depending on the actual format required, you could then use `\section` or define a new list to obtain the automatic numbering.